# multiple epoll control with thread avoid EEXIST

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, epoll

I made TCP/UDP epoll server socket and each socket listening in each other threads. But, `epoll_ctl_return` exist.

I use different ports so, this problem may be solved using fork, but 
I want to handle multiple servers socket in one process and multiple threads.

I read an article in c# multiple server socket. 
is it impossible using epoll?

Or multiple server sockets add epoll?

that's my pseudo code

```
listener* tcpListener = new listener(ip,port, protocolType.tcp);

tcpListener.bind();

std::thread t{listener::listen, tcpListener};

listener* udpListener = new listener(ip,port,protocolType.udp);

udpListener.bind();

std::thread u{listener::listen, udpListener};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where epoll fits in to your description.  If every socket is owned by a separate thread then there is no point to using epoll.  epoll() is used for asynchronous programming, where multiple sockets can be managed by a single thread of execution.

Comment: i read interested your opinion. i reconsider my codes. thanks.